# How does the OS/360 link editor create a tree-structured overlay?

Tags: link-editor, os360

*[This question was raised as part of a [comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27253/how-did-the-os-360-link-editor-achieve-overlay-structuring-at-linkage-time-witho#comment96474_27254) to a [question about controlling the OS360 Link-Editor](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27253/6659) which included a link for [RXS11's Task Builder Manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11d/RSX11D_V6.2_Feb77/DEC-11-OXDLA-D-D_RSX-11D_Task_Builder_Reference_Manual_197603.pdf). Which led to the following comments:*

> Dirkt:  and the PDP-11 one has tree-structured overlays; nice.

> Raffzahn: The same as with the /360 linke editor

> Dirkt: can you edit the answer and include an example of a tree-structured overlay?

*A few more comments forth and back it became clear that this is a complete different issue and maybe born out of reading an old time manual with today's assumption.]*

So: **How does IBM's Link-Editor handle tree structured overlays** and how is that related to the way DEC does.

Answer (score 5):

> **How does IBM's Link-Editor handle tree structured overlays** and how is that related to the way DEC does.

Short and maybe disappointing answer: **Neither of them does tree structured overlays.** That's still the programmers job.

While documentation for both ([Link-Editor](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/360/os/R21.0_Mar72/GC28-6538-9_OS_Linkage_Editor_and_Loader_Release_21_Jan72.pdf),[Task-Builder](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11d/RSX11D_V6.2_Feb77/DEC-11-OXDLA-D-D_RSX-11D_Task_Builder_Reference_Manual_197603.pdf)) features tree diagrams, and talk about module trees, those are only visualisation methods recommended to programmers to be used when creating the commands for either linker. Because linkers are both, despite their fancy names, programs intended to order object modules in linear address space. Also important to note, neither manages overlays at runtime. That's done by some OS service and/or by an overlay manager linked with the root code.

---

### A Closer Look

DEC and IBM differ for most most parts only how information is presented, terminology used and instructions syntax:

- IBM trees have their root (lowest address) at the top, DEC on bottom of a graph (*1).
- What DEC calls co-trees are regions to IBM.
- DEC uses a function-like notation with parentheses and special symbols where IBM does it with a straight sequence of control statements (*2).

### Graphics are Drawn ...

Both manuals offer a simple examples with a single overlay area build from 5 modules with  just three paths, meaning that there are three possible memory layouts. So let's compare them, DEC first (p.5-7):

[image]

So the left side shows a tree while the right is supposed to show the memory layout, addresses growing upward. In both there is a root module always in memory while the remaining four are sharing the overlay address space in form of three different execution paths.

IBM offers a similar structured program on page 65/66:

[image]

Most notable is, as mentioned, the reverse order (*3), otherwise the same. Also, IBM focuses on trees, while DEC continues both types of graphs.

**Everything up to here is all good old manual scribbling on the back of a used punch card.**

### ... and Turned into Notation

As already seen in the first picture the relevant command to produce that 'tree' with DEC's Task Builder is `ROOT X-(Y,Z-(Zl,Z2))` where

- a hyphen relates units that exist sequential in memory
- parentheses are used to build groups that share the same start address (aka overlay each other)
- a comma to list units (within parenthesis)

IBM in turn uses two types of commands to add and group modules. The same definition might look like this:

```
INCLUDE X           
OVERLAY ONE
INCLUDE Y
OVERLAY ONE
INCLUDE Z
OVERLAY TWO
INCLUDE Z1
OVERLAY TWO
INCLUDE Z2
```

Each `INCLUDE` statement adds one or more units to a given section, each `OVERLAY` defines where and in which sequence they are added.

### All the Same

So let's compare both notations:

```
IBM               DEC

INCLUDE X         X
OVERLAY ONE       (
INCLUDE Y         Y
OVERLAY ONE       ,
INCLUDE Z         Z
OVERLAY TWO       (
INCLUDE Z1        Z1
OVERLAY TWO       ,
INCLUDE Z2        Z2
```

A one on one relation (*4). This will stay true for more complex examples, although for multiple regions IBM's OVERLAY will get a second parameter to name a the region. So the difference comes down to the old name-things vs. count-parentheses game. Naming regions is mandatory for IBM, while optional for DEC - at least for simplecases like above.

### The Underlaying Basics

This is maybe a point where programmers, at least some, will note a striking similarity: `OVERLAY <x>` to mark a start address does look quite like handling of address level in Assembly by `ORG <x>`, doesn't it? Overlay linking is all about address level handling, isn't it?

There are no trees or huge dynamic handling. It's all about which segment is active. This one and all related upstream (toward root) segments will be in memory (usually one downstream path as well). So no need to mix it up with fancy structures or management.

---

*[Had a section about how to use a grid structure to build a better visualization for balancing, but removed it as that is very basic CS teaching - or should still be :))]*

---

*1 - Deep rooted (sic) in how either company draws memory maps. IBM like memory is handled, from low address to high address and documents are read (top to bottom),  DEC like some power point graph :))

*2 - To me this (and similar cases) always look like a proof of how functional IT will be designed by a down to earth tradesman vs. what comes out of some ivory tower CS department.

*3 - Or better the right one :))

*4 - Kind like turning an algebraic notation into UPN, saving the closing parenthesis and the hyphen being syntactical sugar:)

Comment: "neither manages overlays at runtime." - this seems to be a difference without a distinction, or something like that.   You can tell TKB you want autoload, and it links in the autoloader routines, found in some standard object library, BUT it also has to construct autoload vectors: so symbol $FOO, which in source is the entry point of some routine in some overlay, is now an address of a root routine to load the overlay and transfer to the original entry point. So, TKB arranges at task-build time the mechanisms to be used at run time.

Comment: The overlay structure is not necessarily a tree, it is a DAG (an overlay segment may be used by more than one upper-level segment; for example both Y and Z2 may want to use an overlay T). Was that handled appropriately?

Comment: @another-dave Guess that depends on one's PoV.

Comment: @LeoB. Not exactly sure what construct you got in mind. If T is a module to be used by Y and Z2, there are two ways to arrange it:a) put it up-path, in this case together with X (A segment can and usually does consist of multiple modules), or have a second overlay region (co-tree for DEC) for T - which only makes sense if there are other overlays like T, otherwise it's, regarding memory use, the same as making it part of the root segment.

Comment: @LeoB. DAGs are handled by making copies, it really is a tree. See the manual referenced in my answer, pages 186-187.

Comment: @dirkt There are no copies, those are separate regions defined and managed independent.

Comment: @Raffzahn "Copies" as in "they are not the same nodes, they are copies of nodes, therefore it's a tree, and not a DAG".

Comment: @dirkt how can they be copies if they exist only once? They are build units a separate, non related region. It's the perfect clue, why it's not a tree - even if it can be drawn as one. Segment region assignment is a fixed 1:1 relation.

Comment: @Raffzahn: A useful dag/tree hybrid is a tree, where each leaf node contains a reference to some possibly-shared data.  If a DAG node would have two parent references, it could be converted to a hybrid tree which contains two copies of that node and all its children, but all such copies' leaf nodes contain references to the same set of shared data holders.  This would require more memory to hold leaf nodes than woudl using a DAG, but if the tree nodes are much smaller than the data identified by leaf nodes, that may be a small price to pay in exchange for the advantages gained by using...

Comment: ... a real tree, such as the ability to traverse the data structure without needing to maintain a stack of visited nodes (since following a link and comparing the previous address with the links in the node would reveal whether one needed to visit the node's left link, right link, or parent).

Comment: @supercat So if it can't be walked without additional data structures it isn't a Tree? Exactly my point. Also, note the only use for that list is to find all upward segments, that is those segments between the desired and rot. There is no need for anything else  thus no need to bloat the data associated. This isn't about pleasing one's CS-Prof, but making overlay systems work in environments with very small memory (64 KiB or less).

Comment: @Raffzahn the **executable code** obviously exists only once. But there are copies of the table entries describing the code, with a different start address for each copy. In this sense the **nodes** (and not the executable code) is copied. You can also just look at the image in the referenced manual, there you'll see the copies.

Comment: @Raffzahn: There's no need to explicitly check for cyclic references when trying to build a tree.  If one has space for e.g. 256 nodes, and cyclic dependencies exist, a problem will be detected when the linker tries to create the 257th node.  When trying to construct a DAG based upon a list of dependencies, depending upon the data structures used, it may be possible to create a cycle within the graph data structure without realizing it, especially if one tries to minimize storage by using fields for different purposes while traversing a graph.  For example, it's possible to traverse a tree...

Comment: @dirkt Now you only need to explain how there can be only one code but multiple tables with multiple addresses. I would assume you're referencing the tree on p.73 of the 1972 manual (please specify). The upper (fig.28) is a pure theoretical drawing, while fgi.2 shows how memory is assigned. Those segments are in their own region with no relation to any other. At fixed address and not copied. There is also only one segment table at the root segment, not copies. After all the linker is not given any information about that relation (p.76). The input does not create a tree nor is it managed as one

Comment: ...which just has "left" and "right" nodes, without using a stack, by having each attempt to visit a node perform the four-way "rotation" `prev_node <- current <- current->left <- current->right <- prev_node".  Hilarity may ensue if cycles exist in a "tree" one attempts to visit in such fashion.

Comment: @supercat no idea what you're talking about and how this is supposed to be related. The segment table does not contain any left or right (or down) relations. Only top.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you; it is not handled as efficiently as I would have expected.

Comment: @Raffzahn OK, think of overlays T1 and T2 in place of T. As a matter of fact, there is no need for the notion of overlay regions. Levelizing the DAG allows to come up with the optimal base address for each segment.

Comment: @LeoB. The problem with T1,T2 is that their location must not conflict with either path of Y or Z1, while working with both. Thus it must be handled independent of both. that's why there's need for a second overlay region, one specifically for T1,T2, which in turn gets managed independent, allowing to minimize reloading/trashing. Doing otehrwise would not save any memory usage or improve handling.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion was mainly about how the `OVERLAY` statement works.

According to the [Linkage Editor](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/360/os/R21.0_Mar72/GC28-6538-9_OS_Linkage_Editor_and_Loader_Release_21_Jan72.pdf) manual <sup>[1]</sup>, pages 74-75, the syntax is

```
OVERLAY <symbol>
```

and it names an interior node in the segment that has multiple children. So the first occurrence defines the name, later occurrences "relocate" the definition back to this node as a new child path. Another variant is

```
OVERLAY <symbol>(REGION)
```

which is used to start a new tree.

For reference, [this manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11d/RSX11D_V6.2_Feb77/DEC-11-OXDLA-D-D_RSX-11D_Task_Builder_Reference_Manual_197603.pdf) describes the RSX11 linker (task builder).

Comparison of the IBM Linkage Editor and the RSX11 Task Builder with respect to overlays:

- Both allow tree-structured overlays
- Both allow multiple trees
- Both are aware of the tree structure at runtime: An action the causes a segment to be loaded will also load all segements on the path to the segment that executes this action.
- Both allow automatic overlay loading as well as manual overlay loading
- For the IBM Linkage Editor, naming an interior node with multiple children is mandatory. For the RSX Task Builder, naming nodes is optional (but required for manual loading), and any node can be named.
- The RSX Task Builder allows either automatic overlay loading or manual overlay loading, but not a mix. The IBM Linkage Editor allows to mix them, and has two macros for manual loading (load and continue processing, or load and wait until the overlay is loaded).
- The RSX Task Loader needs to include a "trampoline" (autoload vector) and changes the call to point to the trampoline. It is not clear how the IBM Linkage Editor implements automatic loading, but as it works in the /360 without virtual memory, it is likely also a trampoline located under the V-type symbol.

---

[1] I found the MVS /370 [Linkage Editor and Loader User's Guide](http://vtda.org/docs/computing/IBM/Mainframe/SysSoft/DataMgmt/SC26-4510-1_MVS-ESALinkageEditorLoaderUsersGuideV3R1.pdf) first, but it is essentially the same. The OVERLAY syntax is on pages 189-190.

Comment: Two points: There is no tree structure and thus no 'awareness' and no 'opening of another tree. Memory is flat, and OVERLAY statements create/name regions within. Also, the /360 does not feature any hardware to support virtual memory. It's what the /370 added to the family.

Comment: @Raffzahn page 200: "When a CALL is used, the requested segment and all segments in its path are loaded if they are not part of the path already in virtual storage". That only works of the overlay manager keeps track of the path and can reconstruct a path, i.e., if it is aware of the tree structure. So while memory is flat, and only one path at a time is stored flattened in flat memory, the tree structure is tracked, without need for user intervention.

Comment: It's much more simple than that. All linkage for calls is done by external ref. (Type V), which the linker points to it's management table.  The table contains either a forward jump to the target address (if loaded) otherwise into the overlay manager.  It then will load the path from the segment containing the desired entry point back to root - which is done by walking the path needed as noted in segment table. The table only contains up-ward linking, it's structure can not be walked from root or at the same level, neither is needed, thus it's not a tree structure, but a (linked) path list.

Comment: You're aware that you're referencing to a different product for a different OS for a different hardware? The question (and the originating one) is about OS 360 for real mode /360 machines of the early 1970s, while your link is for a manual for ESA machines (several generations later) for MVS, a virtual machine system.

Comment: @Raffzahn this manual was hard enough to find. If you have a manual for the linker on the /360 in real mode, including details how this is implemented (trampoline), I'd be really interested. Anyhow, it explains the OVERLAY syntax, which was the part I didn't understand.

Comment: @It's linked right at the start of my answer, isn't it? [Link-Editor](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/360/os/R21.0_Mar72/GC28-6538-9_OS_Linkage_Editor_and_Loader_Release_21_Jan72.pdf)